# Can spacetime really be infinitely curved (e.g by a black hole)? And if it can, wouldn't infinite curvature have infinite energy?

Tags: energy, black-holes, spacetime, singularities

Does infinite curvature of spacetime really exist in physical world?

Comment: At which point do you think general relativity claims spacetime to be "infinitely curved" (note that the "point" at the center of a Schwarzschild black hole is called a "singularity" for a reason)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we get infinite energy from space time (maybe curving it infinitely)?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/295469/)

Answer (score 1):

> Can space time really be infinitely curved (e.g by a black hole)?

A black hole doesn't curve spacetime, a black hole *is* (a region of) highly curved spacetime with, according to General Relativity (GR), a [curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature_invariant_(general_relativity)) [singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_singularity#Curvature) enclosed by an [event horizon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_horizon#Event_horizon_of_a_black_hole).

However, GR is a classical theory and, as far as we know, the physical world is better modeled with quantum theory.  A [quantum theory of gravity](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/quantum-gravity/) is still a work in progress.

Comment: This is Groundhog day, over and over, the same theme.  http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/295469/